# One column bigger than others HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Need to create something this (the bottom table)...

[image: Table Example]

What would be the best method to achieve this. **Considering the gradient and the drop shadow on the last column**. Tried putting a row on top and row on the bottom, but the drop shadow went into each cell.

Comment: Can you atleast show something that you have tried? Do you want a bigger row with shadow? Can you not use width with box-shadow?

Comment: Here is the link to see my progress... https://www.telecomsworldplc.co.uk/phone-and-broadband/business-line-rental-revised.html

Comment: There will be quite literally many ways to achieve that. It really depends on your browser compatibility limitations as to how fiddly it will be. Give us some guidelines that you need to follow.

Comment: Ah i see... I guess CSS3 is out then?

Comment: Any way it can be done really, problem using table cells is that the box shadow goes into each cell, as previously mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit tricky, but I think, this is basically what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/qe2vc/

HTML:

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="legend">
        <table>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Property 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Property 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Property 3</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div><div>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Product A</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Yes</td></tr>
            <tr><td>No</td></tr>
            <tr><td>No</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div><div>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Product B</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Yes</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Yes</td></tr>
            <tr><td>No</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div><div class="featured">
        <table>
            <tr><td>Product C</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Yes</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Yes</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Yes</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
DIV.products > DIV {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
DIV.products > DIV.legend { 
    border: 0; 
}
DIV.products > DIV.featured {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    height: 108px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px -1px #000;
}
```

Basically, have a couple divs next to each other, style one of them differently. Then put a table with the same heights/rows in each box.
With some more styling work, this example can be made to look like your example.

Comment: Bingo! Nearly got it! As you say, just need to do some more styling... result is here! https://www.telecomsworldplc.co.uk/phone-and-broadband/business-line-rental-revised.html As for the answer, that was what I was looking for, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the following style to the fourth column.

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 1px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
border-top: 10px solid #FC8600;
border-bottom: 10px solid #FC7500;
```

- Remove the `<tr>` elements that you're using to add the 10 px border.
- Remove the last cell `border-bottom`.

Comment: Hi, tried this, but it increases the whole row size

Comment: You're right, i didn't notice that.